# Spread operator and destructuring

Tags: typescript, destructuring, spread-syntax

```
interface Item {
    id: string;
    title: string,
}

interface ItemState {
    entities: { [id: string]: Item };
}


const toBeDeleted = { id: '2', title: 'item_2' };

const state: ItemState = {
    entities: {
        '1': { id: '1', title: 'item_1' },
        '2': { id: '2', title: 'item_2' },
        '3': { id: '3', title: 'item_3' }
    }
};

const { [toBeDeleted.id]: deleted, ...remaingEntities } = state; // doesn't work

const newState = { entities: remaingEntities };

// That's what I'm trying to achive with the line, that doesn't work:

// deleted.toBe( { id: '2', title: 'item_2' } )

// newState.toBe( {
//     entities: {
//        '1': { id: '1', title: 'item_1' },
//        '3': { id: '3', title: 'item_3' }
//    }
// })
```

I want to delete an item using the spread operator and destructuring, and destructure 'state' into two parts:

1. the item I want to delete
2. the remaining items

Basically pull out 'state.entities['2']' from state and keep the rest.

Is that even possible, or am I mixing two concepts here?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with destructuring.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with destructuring. I would just copy state and remove element manually

Comment: Is this just a typo and you mean `= state.entities` instead of `= state`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRB8Xw)?

Comment: Huh, TIL you can use computed property names in destructuring assignment...

Comment: @jcalz
I mean 'state'.It shoud be spreaded into

entities: {
        '1': { id: '1', title: 'item_1' },
        '3': { id: '3', title: 'item_3' }
}

and not into:

{
        '1': { id: '1', title: 'item_1' },
        '3': { id: '3', title: 'item_3' }
}

Comment: But `state` doesn't contain any entities to spread, it contains a single property *named* `entities`, and the value of that property is what you want to spread.  Given that changing `state` to `state.entities` in that code seems to behave exactly as you want, I'm struggling to understand what you're doing. You could also write it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/Wo808w), but that's not really any different. Could you triple check and then tell me whether or not this is just a typo or a disconnect or something?

Comment: @jcalz you're right. The two playgrounds are helpful. There it works exactly as intended

Comment: So what should we do here?  Close it as a typo?  Or write up an answer that essentially says "you don't want to spread from `state`; you want to spread from `state.entities`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jcalz wrote in the comments, spreading not from 'state' but from 'state.entities' did it. Thank you jcalz!

The following line should be changed:

const { [toBeDeleted.id]: deleted, ...remaingEntities } = state; // WRONG

const { [toBeDeleted.id]: deleted, ...remaingEntities } = state.entities // CORRECT

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted answer if it solves the problem from your question. It would be nice if you could elaborate (with code) in your answer what exactly needs to be changed according to jcalz.

Comment: @user643011
Thanks for the tip. Edited the answer accordingly and marked it as accepted.